# QGIS, What is the reason for wrong scale and wrong areas?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, openlayers, scale, measurements

I am currently working with QGIS and loaded openstreetmap as a basemap (web-> OpenLayers plugin), it is in WGS84/ Pseudo Mercator. For some reason the scale is not correct. For example a distance in my project results about two times as long as the same distance for example on google maps. Does anyone know what the reason could be?

Comment: Have you verified that you are looking at the same units - feet vs meters?

Comment: thanks for the fast respond. Yes, I did check it, its all meter. I opened my data also with another map as a reference (WGS84). Then the areas I measured are closer to the size they are supposed to have, but still too big.

Comment: Could you add screenshots of what you are seeing to the question? It will help us troubleshoot.

Comment: I think its a problem of the coordinate system. But openstreetmap has Wgs84/ Pseudo Mercator as standard setting, so I wonder why the size problem occurs.

Comment: Try setting the project crs to regular WGS84 (NOT pseudo mercator).

Comment: I finally found the mistake: I changed the coordinate systems of the layers, but not the coordinate system of the project, thats why Qgis calculated wrong. Thank you anyway

Comment: Please consider including your comment as an answer and accepting it. That way we can consider this question resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the deprecated OpenLayers plugin - it's got known issues with scale and CRS handling. Use the regularly maintained QuickMapServices plugin instead.